# How do I glitch into the room where the Strange Figure is Bee Swarm Simulator?

Tags: roblox

In Bee Swarm Simulator, there's a maze next to the Ticket Tent. In the maze is a blocked off room with a person and it's called the Strange Figure. It's possible to glitch inside the room, so I want to know how to. I tried using gumdrops, jumping around, and clicking, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Activate shift lock in settings. Stand at a corner (pointing outwards toward you like a spike) near the room. Quickly turn in a full 360 then into the corner while walking into the corner, using WASD to keep direction correct. Please look up a better guide for the shift lock glitch, as this explaination is not as fully developed. =)